# Dynamic Conditional Formatting Formula Based on Relative Cell References

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I've read this forum for many Excel-related issues over the past 3-4 years, always finding answers when needed... but this time, I'm stumped.

I'm trying to use Conditional Formatting based on a formula to highlight values that are out out of range based on a cell that is a defined distance away. Specifically, the cell I will be attempting to format will be 8 cells to the right of the reference cell. (e.g., comparing R13 to J13, where J13 is the reference value). So the "Lower Spec Limit" is automatically generated from column J to Q, and the user inputs results in columns R to Y.

I would like to accomplish this without having 8 formulas, but so far I have been unable to figure out the right combination of AND/OR statements that will allow me to apply a single formula from row R to Y, where R>J, S>K, T>L, etc. are the conditions to be met.

In a nutshell, the formula I was using was basically:

```
=OR($R13>$J13,$S13>$K13,$T13>$L13)
```

Within the Conditional Formatting line. Of course, I then realized that this would format the entire affected range when any condition was met. I also tried to consider whether there was even data in the cell yet, but that got to be a messy way to highlight the entire range again anyway.

From other entries on this site, I've found that I need to:

- Avoid INDIRECT references (can be unstable)
- Potentially use OFFSET (although I'm unfamiliar within Excel formulas, only used in VBA in the past)

There will be other users for this spreadsheet, so that will have to be a condition.

Is this a feasible task, or would I be better off to have the 8 formulas (which will be 16 if I highlight based on "pass" and "fail" criteria)?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: May have misunderstood but can't you just remove the dollar signs and make the formulas relative?

Comment: Wow. I feel silly now. I definitely tried this formula yesterday; however, I had other formats in place at the time. I didn't isolate that formula on its own. I moved past it and tried from scratch (no other formatting) and didn't retry this avenue. Thank you so much @SJR , I guess I just needed fresh eyes!